# Plot mesh stored as vertices and faces

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a mesh stored as a collection of 3D faces and vertices e.g.

```
v = np.array([[0,0,0],
              [1,0,0],
              [1,1,0],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,0,1],
              [1,0,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [0,1,1]])
f = np.array([[0,2,1],
              [0,3,2],
              [1,2,6],
              [1,6,5],
              [0,5,4],
              [0,1,5],
              [4,5,6],
              [6,7,4],
              [3,7,6],
              [6,2,3],
              [0,4,7],
              [7,3,0]])
```

Where `v` describes the coordinates of the nodes, and `f` the index of the vertices of each face.

I than have a vector `C` containing a scalar at each node e.g.

```
C = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

I'd like to plot this as a mesh using the scalar in `C` as color map for each node. This is similar to what is achieved in Matlab using the `patch('Faces',F,'Vertices',V)` command ([doc](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#bur8xd4-1))

Is it possible to achieve this with matplotlib or, more generally, with python?

**BONUS QUESTION:**

More generally, my faces can have a variable number of vertices. In my matrix I have both tri and quad faces, where the tri are padded with np.nan as fourth node.

Is it possible to plot a mesh with both 3 and 4 sided faces without splitting the quads into tri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot a `Poly3DCollection` with the edgecoordinates of the faces `v[f]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, art3d

v = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,1,0], 
              [0,0,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1], [0,1,1]])

f = np.array([[0,2,1], [0,3,2], [1,2,6], [1,6,5],
              [0,5,4], [0,1,5], [4,5,6], [6,7,4],
              [3,7,6], [6,2,3], [0,4,7], [7,3,0]])

C = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

norm = plt.Normalize(C.min(), C.max())
colors = plt.cm.viridis(norm(C))

pc = art3d.Poly3DCollection(v[f], facecolors=colors, edgecolor="black")
ax.add_collection(pc)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you will need to colorize the faces, not the nodes (as nodes can't have colors) - so I invented a few more values in `C`.

Comment: Is it impossible to have shaded faces as this https://uk.mathworks.com/help/examples/graphics/win64/ControlFaceColorsWhenUsingCoordinateDataExample_02.png ?

Comment: Nothing is impossible. But there is no built-in option for that. One could think of subsampling each face into several new faces, each with its own color. Too complicated if you ask me.